# How to identify the 32 bit data-sitekey of ReCaptcha V2 to obtain a valid response programmatically using Selenium and Python Requests?

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, recaptcha, 2captcha

Pretty much new with captcha and Python requests. The [captcha documentation](https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api#solving_recaptchav2_new) says to copy the value of `data-sitekey` parameter.

Here was my attempt, using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) to open the url and using Python `requests` to get a response.

```
mainurl = 'https://imagetyperz.xyz/automation/recaptcha-v2.html'
driver.get(mainurl)
data_sitekey_class = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "g-recaptcha"))).get_attribute("data-sitekey")
print(data_sitekey_class)
src_css_selector = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[role='presentation']").get_attribute("src")
print(src_css_selector)
keygoogle = src_css_selector[52:92]
print('Site Key = ', keygoogle)
data_post = {'key': data_sitekey_class, 'method': 'userrecaptcha', 'googlekey': keygoogle, "pageurl": mainurl}
response = requests.post(url = 'https://2captcha.com/in.php', data = data_post )
print(response)
print(response.text)
```

I am getting `200` as response:

```
6LdXeIYUAAAAAFmFKJ6Cl3zo4epRZ0LDdOrYsvRY
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=6LdXeIYUAAAAAFmFKJ6Cl3zo4epRZ0LDdOrYsvRY&co=aHR0cHM6Ly9pbWFnZXR5cGVyei54eXo6NDQz&hl=en&v=vJuUWXolyYJx1oqUVmpPuryQ&size=normal&cb=r14cgu7t25ul
Site Key =  6LdXeIYUAAAAAFmFKJ6Cl3zo4epRZ0LDdOrYsvRY
<Response [200]>
ERROR_WRONG_USER_KEY
```

which is due to:

```
ERROR_WRONG_USER_KEY
```

Further, [Error](https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api#in_errors) section mentions:

```
Error code: ERROR_WRONG_USER_KEY
Description: You've provided key parameter value in incorrect format, it should contain 32 symbols.
Action: Stop sending requests. Check your API key.
```

Finally, [Solving Captchas](https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api#solving_captchas) section mentions:

Get your API key from your account settings page. Each user is given a unique authentication token, we call it API key. It's a 32-characters string that looks like:

```
1abc234de56fab7c89012d34e56fa7b8
```

Where as the `data-sitekey` I am seeing is:

```
6LdXeIYUAAAAAFmFKJ6Cl3zo4epRZ0LDdOrYsvRY
```

which is **41** bit.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: UNRELATED - I have a question on selenium here. Hoping you could help. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60678312/do-we-need-to-have-both-selenium-server-and-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data-sitekey` represented through 41-characters string works just fine. The error `ERROR_WRONG_USER_KEY` occurred as I never had a valid [API key](https://2captcha.com/setting) ready in the first place. Even with **Zero** balance in your account, you can successfully obtain a `<Response [200]>` with text as `ERROR_ZERO_BALANCE` as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  import requests

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  mainurl = 'https://imagetyperz.xyz/automation/recaptcha-v2.html'
  driver.get(mainurl)
  data_sitekey = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "g-recaptcha"))).get_attribute("data-sitekey")
  print(data_sitekey)
  api_key = '--------------------------------'
  data_post = {'key': api_key, 'method': 'userrecaptcha', 'googlekey': data_sitekey, "pageurl": mainurl}
  response = requests.post(url = 'https://2captcha.com/in.php', data = data_post )
  print(response)
  print(response.text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  6LdXeIYUAAAAAFmFKJ6Cl3zo4epRZ0LDdOrYsvRY
  <Response [200]>
  ERROR_ZERO_BALANCE
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Had the same error. I was using `headers=header` instead of `data=header`.