# Do we need to have both selenium server and selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, maven, selenium

Here is a [udemy course](https://www.udemy.com/course/selenium-webdriver-advanced-framework/) (from "Lets Kode It") to develop a web automation framework with selenium. The instructor has created a Java project with Maven. The dependencies mainly needed are hamcrest, testng and selenium. But, the instructor insists that selenium-server dependency should also be included because "maven might have a glitch and it might not get all the dependencies of selenium-java (screenshot attached)".

My question is that does this ever happen and why? It seems odd to me that every project which only needs selenium webdriver should also include selenium-server.

Moreover, in another post (screenshot NOT included), the instructor says that one must include Junit dependency also because of similar reasons. It feels odd that we have to include Junit in every project just due to "potential conflicts".

[image]

Comment: "maven might have a glitch" - sounds like your instructor had issues and didn't dig to figure out the details. Selenium Server is needed if you want to start it right in the tests (which is one of use cases), but otherwise it's not needed.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev - "if you want to start it right in the tests ". Sorry, I did not understand this. The course only implements a few simple tests for a simple website and packages them into a framework. I am not sure how selenium server would be needed for such a use case.

Comment: It may be late . You don't need selenium-server-standalone.jar .if  selenium-java included https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/4.0.0-alpha-6

Answer (score -1):

Selenium server is needed when you used to run your tests using Selenium Grid.
For more information please read [this](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) 
In Maven projects if you try to use Selenium libs you must add Selenium Maven Dependency for particular programming language (java, python...), but you don't need to include Selenium server if you don't use Grid for your tests.
I suggest you to read more about Maven and see if Modules can save your duplicated dependencies.