# "NoSuchSessionError: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID" when running a simple Selenium Runner test

Tags: macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jestjs, selenium-chromedriver

I just installed the latest version of Selenium Runner

```
npm install -g selenium-side-runner
```

on my Mac High Sierra.  I'm running node v14.1.0.  I'm using Chrome Driver v 83.  I want to run a very simple file that simply opens a page, waiting for an element on that page to be present.  However, I'm getting a "NoSuchSessionError: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID" error.

The Selenium Runner .side file in question is

```
$ cat selenium/KarmaDecayGetResults.side
{
  "id": "9664bd47-b18f-405f-9bd3-06014919ca7e",
  "version": "2.0",
  "name": "KarmaDecay",
  "url": "http://karmadecay.com",
  "tests": [
    {
      "id": "8f462171-01b8-4247-87b9-40e2d1fef143",
      "name": "KarmaDecay",
      "commands": [
        {
          "id": "c297319b-4350-4f04-b72e-1a347a67100c",
          "comment": "",
          "command": "open",
          "target": "/r/gifs/comments/gz5v5j/caracal_visits_jimmy_kimmel_gets_shy_and_tries_to/",
          "targets": [],
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "id": "32f35ed7-1a28-4540-a93d-3cb8ba0e012a",
          "comment": "",
          "command": "pause",
          "target": "",
          "targets": [],
          "value": "2000"
        },
        {
          "id": "95261633-22ff-4477-ab6f-7b3354bea8b9",
          "comment": "",
          "command": "setWindowSize",
          "target": "1440x900",
          "targets": [],
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "id": "fbf35ed7-1a28-4540-a93d-3cb8ba0e012a",
          "comment": "",
          "command": "waitForElementPresent",
          "target": "id=content",
          "targets": [],
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "id": "aed35ed7-1a28-4540-a93d-3cb8ba0e012a",
          "comment": "",
          "command": "waitForElementVisible",
          "target": "id=content",
          "targets": [],
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "id": "fbf59ed7-1a28-4540-a93d-3cb8ba0e012a",
          "comment": "",
          "command": "pause",
          "target": "",
          "targets": [],
          "value": "2000"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "suites": [
    {
      "id": "91809d77-24c1-457b-8266-516b2fc58555",
      "name": "Default Suite",
      "persistSession": false,
      "parallel": false,
      "timeout": 300,
      "tests": [
        "8f462171-01b8-4247-87b9-40e2d1fef143"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "urls": [
    "http://karmadecay.com/"
  ],
  "plugins": []
}
```

Below is the output of running the file ...

```
$ PATH=/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/article_project/selenium/dev:/usr/local/bin:$PATH /usr/local/bin/selenium-side-runner -c "goog:chromeOptions.args=[--headless,--nogpu] browserName=chrome" selenium/KarmaDecayGetResults.side

 FAIL  ./DefaultSuite.test.js (301.959s)
  Default Suite
    ✕ KarmaDecay (300540ms)

  ● Default Suite › KarmaDecay

    : Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 300000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 300000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:

       8 | jest.setTimeout(300000);
       9 | describe("Default Suite", () => {
    > 10 |   it("KarmaDecay", async () => {
         |   ^
      11 |     await tests["KarmaDecay"](driver, vars);
      12 |     expect(true).toBeTruthy();
      13 |   });

      at new Spec (../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Spec.js:116:22)
      at Suite.<anonymous> (DefaultSuite.test.js:10:3)

  ● Default Suite › KarmaDecay

    NoSuchSessionError: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used.

      at ../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:729:38
      at Object.thenFinally [as finally] (../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:124:12)
          at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at WebdriverEnvironment.global.cleanup (../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/jest-environment-selenium/dist/index.js:30:7)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        302.159s
Ran all test suites.
```

Do I need to be doing something different to get my test to run cleanly?

Answer (score 3):

### [invalid session id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/InvalidSessionID)

The **invalid session ID** error is a [WebDriver error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors) that occurs when the server does not recognize the unique session identifier. This happens if the *session has been deleted* or if the *session ID is invalid*.

A WebDriver session can be deleted through either of the following ways:

- [Explicit session deletion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/InvalidSessionID#Explicit_session_deletion): A WebDriver session is explicitly deleted when explicitly invoking the `quit()` method.
- [Implicit session deletion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/InvalidSessionID#Implicit_session_deletion): A WebDriver session is implicitly deleted when you close the last window or tab invoking `close()`.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid session id using Selenium with ChromeDriver and Chrome through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56483403/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-invalid-session-id-using/56492149#56492149)

---

### This usecase

I don't see any such error within your code block. However your main error seems to be...

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 300000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 300000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:
```

...which implies that the `Async callback` being referred to in the error is getting timedout even with *timeout* set as `300000`:

```
jest.setTimeout(300000);
```

The real issue is with the url of [**KarmaDecay**](http://karmadecay.com/) which contains a [**hCaptcha**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501524/how-does-recaptcha-3-know-im-using-selenium-chromedriver/55502835#55502835) to keep off *automated bots*.

- URL Snapshot:

[image: hCaptcha_Karmadecay]

---

### Conclusion

As per your test setup to execute the `selenium-side-runner` within the website http://karmadecay.com/ first you have to interact with the [captcha](/questions/tagged/captcha) to get authenticated and then run your tests.

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on how to interact with [recaptcha](/questions/tagged/recaptcha) in:

- [How to identify the 32 bit data-sitekey of ReCaptcha V2 to obtain a valid response programmatically using Selenium and Python Requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60150761/how-to-identify-the-32-bit-data-sitekey-of-recaptcha-v2-to-obtain-a-valid-respon)
- [Find the reCAPTCHA element and click on it — Python + Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917157/find-the-recaptcha-element-and-click-on-it-python-selenium/53917309#53917309)
- [How to click on the reCaptcha using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264221/how-to-click-on-the-recaptcha-using-selenium-and-java/55265044#55265044)

---

### Another aspect

If the initial tests works fine but for the rest of your tests you get a *session ID* error most possibly the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) controled *Browsing Context* is getting detected and hence blocking the next requests.

There are different reasons for the *WebDriver* controled *Web Browser* to get detected and simultaneously get blocked. You can find a couple of detailed discussion in:

- [Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/62520191#62520191)
- [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not clear reading through these what actions I need to take to get everything to work.  In as far as SO discourages links because they get broken over time, could you include the steps I would need to make my script run successfully?

Comment: @Dave Checkout the updated answer with a _Conclusion_ section. All of the links referred within the _Conclusion_ section involves steps in details on how to interact with captcha / recaptcha. let me know if you need further help.